# swift 4 Google Map - how to update marker position using gesture.position

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers, swift4

In `viewDidLoad` i added `gesturerecognizers` to `mapView` and also set true the `consumeGestureInView`
and in the handleTap Method I convert the touch point into latLng and then set the marker position with latLng but the marker move slow very slow

```
self.mapView.settings.consumesGesturesInView = true
for gestureRecognizer in self.mapView.gestureRecognizers! {
                                gestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MapViewController.handleTap(_:)))
}

      @objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
                var allMarkers = markers
                if(sender.numberOfTouches == 1){
                    var positions = CGPoint()
                    var newPosition = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
                    let currentZoom = self.mapView.camera.zoom

                    switch (sender.state){
                    case .began:
                        positions = sender.location(in: self.mapView)
                        newPosition = self.mapView.projection.coordinate(for: positions)
                        let ind = self.getNearbymarkers(position: newPosition,markers:allMarkers)
                        allMarkers[ind].position = newPosition
                        self.mapView.settings.scrollGestures = false
                        mapView(self.mapView, didBeginDragging: allMarkers[ind])
                        self.mapView.settings.scrollGestures = true
                        break
                    case .ended:
                        positions = sender.location(in: self.mapView)
                        newPosition = self.mapView.projection.coordinate(for: positions)
                        let ind = self.getNearbymarkers(position: newPosition,markers:allMarkers)
                        print(ind)
                        allMarkers[ind].position = newPosition
                        self.mapView.settings.scrollGestures = false
                        mapView(self.mapView, didEndDragging: allMarkers[ind])
                        self.mapView.settings.scrollGestures = true
                        break
                    case .changed:
                        positions = sender.location(in: self.mapView)
                        newPosition = self.mapView.projection.coordinate(for: positions)
                        let ind = self.getNearbymarkers(position: newPosition,markers:allMarkers)
                        print(ind)
                        allMarkers[ind].position = newPosition
                        self.mapView.settings.scrollGestures = false
                        mapView(self.mapView, didDrag: allMarkers[ind])
                        self.mapView.settings.scrollGestures = true
                        break
                    default:
                        break
                    }
            }
        }
```

The issue is when this line execute then the marker rendered slow       `allMarkers[ind].position = newPosition`
        like my finger move fast then the marker looks like moving behind the finger

Comment: I wanted to move marker like panGestureRecognizer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for my experience, there are no easy built-in solutions in GM framework for that. Unfortunately, the only interactive event that `GMSMarker` objects allow you to track (almost with no delays) is a simple tap, which triggers a corresponding callback in mapView's delegate. If you want something more complex, you have to implement stuff with your own custom marker view placed above map while performing drag&drop operation. Here is the algorithm:

1) Add a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to the mapView. Set it's delegate to resolve conflicts with mapView's built-in gestureRecognizers.

2) When you start panning, in `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` decide whether the user apply pan to map or to a marker. If to marker, allow panGR to fire (`return true`).

3) Hide `GMSMarker` object which you wish to move (set opacity to zero or just remove from map)

4) Insert your custom independent *MarkerView* (which visually duplicates the removed one at step 3) under the finger position

5) Move this custom view with the panGR's updates.

6) On finger release, replace your custom *MarkerView* with the `GMSMarkerView` on the final finger location in order to pin in to the map back.